# I can't view the database content on a php page

Tags: php, mysql

I can't view the database content on php page 
I want to fetch data using ID
thats the code :

```
<?php
//connect with database
$servername = "localhost";
$userdbname = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "users";
$usid = 0;
$docname = '';


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $userdbname, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$usid;
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $conn->close();
    $URLS = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $docname= $row['docname'];
    }
    header("Location:Editeform.php");
}

?>
```

This is the form I am trying to view the data in :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" name="docname" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php echo $users['docname']; ?>" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: `$conn->close();` < start by removing that; you closed it too soon.

Comment: `$docname= $row['docname'];` < you didn't echo that. You only declared it.

Comment: `$URLS = array();` < that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how to echo it ?

Comment: `echo $docname= $row['docname'];` which is valid syntax. You can also echo the variable assignment below it, which basically does the same thing.

Comment: This code seems to be wrong. 1) i do not think there is needed to close connection, 2) i do not think there is while loop needed 3) as there is redirect after while loop i do not see how your input could possible fill up. ..

Comment: You have a point about the header being there @Ingus good catch. I missed that one. I need a 2nd cup of coffee :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example how it could look with `PDO` (as i see you are just starting and i suggest to learn `PDO` as its not that hard)
This way you also are safe from SQL injections.

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$usid = 0;
$docname = '';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$usid]); 

$row = $stmt->fetch();
$docname = $row['docname'];

echo '
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" name="docname" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="'.$docname.'" />
</div>';
```

P.S. I have not tested it so fill your details and give it a try!

Here is really good website to learn all about PDO: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: While it might be a good idea in general to use PDO I fail to see how it solves the problem.

Comment: @Dharman Look at original code and read comment. .. You will find out ;)

Comment: I assume the original question was how to display the data received from DB, but it is not very clear.